# How to store custom field uploaded photo into database in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field(file) in my pagetemplate.

```
<input type="file" name="head-photo" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control form-control" id="uploadImage" aria-invalid="false" />
```

How can i store uploaded file(photo) in to my wordpress database?

Comment: This is post meta or what is the field for

Comment: Have to post the field as of WP standards.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this field to save any post detail than, you can save this field value as add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
for update
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);

Please check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a simple form with input file you can use [media_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) function,

Example handler on form submit

```
// Load necessary files
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

// Simple image attachment data             
$atts_data = array(
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(), // just an example
);

// Process image upload
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'input-file-name', 0, $atts_data );

// verify upload 
if ( !is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) { 
    // Media upload success, 
} else {
    // Media Upload Fail
}
```